# How to pass the drodown selected value in thymeleaf to spring boot controller

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Please help me with any working code.I am trying from since one week not getting the solution.

Comment: how should we help you if you dont show us any code which is not working?

Answer (score 6):

Give name attribute to the html select element, you can access the selected value of drop down in the controller from HttpServletRequest  object as below.

```
  <form role="form" id="sendAddress" th:action=@{/sendAddress} method="post">
        <select class="form-control" name="nameOfCity">
            <option value="">Select City</option>
            <option value="HYD">Hyderabad</option>
            <option value="MUM">Mumbai</option>
            <option value="DEL">Delhi</option>
        </select>
    </form>



    @RequestMapping(value={"/sendAddress"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String messageCenterHome(Model model,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request) {

        String selectedCity= request.getParameter("nameOfCity")
        //return view 
    }
```

Comment: I guess, this is not the properThymeleaf solution, but it works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Java MVC frameworks encapsulate Servlet APIs and common functionality is provided to us using the framework's simpler APIs.

For a task as common as retrieving a parameter value from a request, Spring MVC and Boot use the `@RequestParam` annotation to retrieve the parameter value selected from a select with option tag.  So [ak38](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7005973/ak38)'s code would not need to use `HttpServletRequest` at all to get the parameter; instead, it would just annotate a paramter of the controller method the request calls:

**HTML Form**:

```
<form role="form" id="sendAddress" th:action=@{/sendAddress} method="post">
    <select class="form-control" name="*nameOfCity*">
        <option value="">Select City</option>
        <option value="HYD">Hyderabad</option>
        <option value="MUM">Mumbai</option>
        <option value="DEL">Delhi</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

**Controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/sendAddress"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String messageCenterHome(**@RequestParam** String *nameOfCity*) {
    // value of nameOfCity is now value of "nameOfCity" paramter,
    // that is, the value of the option tag selected
    // return view 
}
```

Try it out, if you haven't already, as I've just seen this now and it's been a few months since the question was posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form th:action="@{/search}" th:object="${searchRequest}" method="post">    
    <select th:field="*{parkType}">
        <option value="1">Test1</option>
        <option value="2">Test2</option>
    </select>           
</form>

@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String searchParks(@ModelAttribute(value = "searchRequest") SearchRequest searchRequest, Model model) {
   
    searchRequest.getParkType(); // to get option value

    return "listings";
}

@lombok.Data
public class SearchRequest {
   private String name;
   private String parkType;
}
```